# Firewall setting are correct but port still closed form outside

Tags: firewall, remote, database, port-forwarding

I setting up machien for connect to postgresql remotly
I check somthing and it's apeare all things is correct

Checking the port status :

```
$> sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN | grep 5432

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 18134/postgres
```

Checking the firewall

```
$> sudo ufw status | grep 5432

5432 ALLOW Anywhere
```

Ping inside machine work :

```
$> telnet 185.235.x.x 5432

Connected to 185.235.x.x
```

But when call from outside of machine

```
 $> telnet 185.235.x.x 5432
  
 Connecting ... (And then timeout)
```

What should I do else ?

**Update**

the pg_hba.cof :

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: Are you connecting from the local network or an external network?

Comment: Allowing connections to your database from the internet is not a very clever idea.

Comment: Please add your relevant `pg_hba.conf` setting --> See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278379/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-all-incoming-connections

Comment: @Irsu85
From external netwrok
The machine has an static ip

Comment: @pLumo
yes but it's for debuging. I add this to question now